# Spring JDBC Template- Decrypt password

Tags: java, spring, encryption, jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC template for establishing the connection with the database. The password is in the encrypted format and want to decrypt it with the help of JDBC template. In order to implement the same, I came to know that I have to override "DriverManagerDataSource" I tried to implement the same but have not succeeded.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="MyclassName">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

`public class MyclassName extends DriverManagerDataSource {`

```
 @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        String password = super.getPassword();
        //External API decryption call
    EncrypterClassName encrypterClassName = new EncrypterClassName();
        return encrypterClassName.decrypt(password);
    }
```

}

I know I have to change the `<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"`  to call the class I have implemented but not sure How to do the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written my own [ProperyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) which is invoked whenever a variable has to be replaced.

```
jdbc.password={base64}yourEncryptedSecret
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
  extends org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

  @Override
  protected String convertPropertyValue(final String originalValue) {
    String cryptString = "{base64}";
    if (originalValue.startsWith(cryptString)) {
      BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
      String decodedPassword = null;
      try {
        decodedPassword = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(originalValue.substring(cryptString.length())));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return decodedPassword;
    }
    return originalValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help...Have implemented the same for my application. However I am still wondering why the approach asked in the question does not work.